# JavaScript not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jsp

Trying to show the preview of images on select option.Below code is working fine in Firefox but not in Internet Explorer.

i have tried to put an alert to display the scr of image , it shows correct path in Firefox but in IE it shows garbeg value like instead of 1.jpg it shows %01.jpg

Any idea how to make it run on IE ?

newAray contain the image name  like 1.jpg ,2.jpg ....

[image]

This is the code :

```
   <form  id = " delete_image" action="DeleteImages.jsp" method="post" >
<select  id = "image_id_delete"  name= "image_id_delete"  onchange="CngColor(this);" style="color:#4B616A; background-color:#eaeced; border:1px solid #939fa4; height:26px; width:120px; padding-bottom: 4px; text-align:center;">
<option value=""><---Select---></option>
<%

for(int i=0;i<newAray.size();i++) 
{ %> 


<option > <%= newAray.get(i) %></option>
<% 
}

%>
</select>


&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<img id="Img1" src="images/1.jpg" width=100 height=100 >

<input type="submit" value= "Delete" style="color:#ffffff; background-color:#939fa4; border:1px solid #4b616a; font-weight: bold; height: 27px; padding-bottom: 3px; cursor: pointer;" >


</form>
```

Javascript :

```
    function CngColor(obj){
index=obj.selectedIndex;
alert(""  + document.getElementById('Img1').src);
document.getElementById('Img1').src= 'images/'+obj.options[index].value;
}
```

Comment: i think jsp is the part of java :)

Comment: How exactly does it fail in IE?  What is this "Img1" element - it does not appear in the code you posted.  Are there errors in the IE developer console?

Comment: yes but since java has many other parts the website introduced jsp tag!!

Comment: JavaScript operates on the DOM generated by the HTML. Show us the HTML, not the JSP that generates it.

Comment: no errors at consol ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for response.
Got the answer :

```
function CngColor(obj){
index=obj.selectedIndex;

document.getElementById('Img1').src= 'images/'+obj.options[index].text;
//cahnged value to text
}
```

Attribute `"value"` doesnt work in some version of Internet Explorer so read the value from the `"text"` field of the Option object.